# Type mismatch: inferred type is Model but List<Model> was expectedd

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

I'm using the room library in a Mvvm architecture application.

There is a main piece and a detail piece.

I go to the detail fragment with id. So I pull the ID from the room. But I will use recyclerview in detail fragment. As you know, there is a list in the adapter class. I am also pulling objects from livedata. These two do not overlap. Do you have a suggestion about it?

This is the detail trailer.
I go to the detail fragment by clicking on Home Fragment. Of course, the relevant information in the list I clicked on will be in the detail section. Think of it like a news site. But I'm going to extract the identity from the elaborate fragmentary room. But I will use recylerview in the detail trailer, but pull it out of the room. The ID and list on the adapter do not match.

Output of the error = Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but List was expected

```
private var uuidd=0
private lateinit var Biewmodell:Bilimdetayviewmodel
private lateinit var bindingdetay:FragmentBdetayBinding

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)



    arguments?.let {
        uuidd = BdetayFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it).uuidd
    }

    val viewmodelll:Bilimdetayviewmodel by viewModels()
    Biewmodell=viewmodelll
    Biewmodell.roomgit(uuidd)
    observer()


}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    bindingdetay=DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_bdetay, container, false)


    return bindingdetay.root
}
fun observer(){
    Biewmodell.getroomlivedata.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { model ->
        model?.let {
            val adapterr = dAdapterd(requireContext(),it)
            bindingdetay.adapterr=adapterr


        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full error message in your question, including the stacktrace.  Also, please format your code correctly and remove unnecessary blank lines.  You are expecting others to spend their valuable time helping you.  The least you can do is do all you can to make your question as easy to read as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot see the issue at a first glance. However, if you want to try using Jetpack Compose, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-room-using-kotlin-flow-in-jetpack-compose-7a720dec35f5) will definitely help. Here is also the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/RoomJetpackCompose).

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: No it's not about jetpack compose. I fixed my question, I hope it's clearer

Comment: Can you show the line that is throwing that error?

Comment: error line. hope you can help.                                                                                              val adapterr = dAdapterd(requireContext(),it)